# How to execute restart.txt ruby on rails shared hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting

i've created restart.txt in the tmp folder, but when i upload some changes to the site, there's nothing changing, so how can i execute the restart.txt manually? or it should start automatically?

Answer (score 4):

You don't execute it, you touch it.

```
cd /path/to/your/app && touch tmp/restart.txt
```

This is a way to signal Passenger to restart workers. I don't know about your shared hosting environment, though (will it work there or not).

Comment: its in the remote hosting, i am on windows, what i need to use that touch?

Comment: You need to SSH to remote machine (use PUTTY, for example)

Comment: is necessary ssh?, because i have only ftp

Comment: ONly have ftp - just re-upload restart.txt each time.

Comment: @MisterPHP ask your hosting provider for an ssh connection

Comment: I'had used the script file and there was also the serv file, used them all like ./serv restart, ruby script restart or script restart, but there's no changes, i am in the "current" folder, there also are revision folders, i don't know in which folder i need to do that?, i've tried all there's still no changes, what i am doing wrong?